# Fortran memory mangement for dummy arrays

Tags: memory, memory-management, fortran, subroutine, intel-fortran

I have a quantum mechanical wave function propagation program, that uses large arrays to store the wavefunciton, about 3 billion elements in size, in a large grid. (Thats a propietary code so I can't show it here publically) Now this wavefunctions/ large array is passed around to different subroutine for doing different calculation. So, obviously those subroutine also have dummy arrays to hold the the input array. Now my question is how fortran manages memory when passing around such large array. Does it allocate individual memory space to hold those dummy arrays? Does it cost performance and time to pass large array through subroutine argument? What is recommened in such situations?
For a simple test I removed those subroutine and moved the codes from inside the subroutine to the main program as much as possible and I noticed about 5% less memory usage and about 10% less time required.

Comment: Well, I would assume that this depends a lot on your compiler and compiler flags. Which compiler and which flags are you using?

Comment: There is no concise general answer to your questions as there are many factors which affect things (compiler capabilities and choices, as mentioned, but also what the code looks like, attributes of dummy and actual arguments, sizes, etc). The best thing to do is look at specific code, and you've already done that and can see an effect.

Comment: I'm using ifort with O3 optimization.

Comment: I've added the implementation being used as a tag as I don't think this question is answerable without reference to the implementation

Answer (score 2):

The Fortran language itself is mostly silent on the mechanics of HOW something is accomplished - it sets out the rules for how a standard-conforming program should behave. That said, if you are simply passing a whole array by its name, what you will find (especially with ifort) is that the array is passed by reference (address) or, if the dummy argument in the called procedure is assumed-shape, assumed-rank or polymorphic, by descriptor (a data structure describing the array but not the data itself.) The only time a copy would be made is if you pass a non-contiguous array section.

Since you are using ifort, you may want to try out whole-program optimization (-ipo), and enable optimization reports to get hints on where things could be improved.

Comment: I'd hope there's a copy if the dummy argument has the VALUE attribute.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that. The VALUE attribute creates an anonymous, writeable copy of the actual argument, and passes that by reference. (It does not mean "pass by value", unless the called routine also has the `BIND(C)` attribute.)

Comment: So in a short, dummy arrays doesn't take extra physical memory, unless they are passed as non contiguous array

Comment: Correct (with the exception @francescalus pointed out).